# Given an array A of size N, find all combination of four elements in the array whose sum is equal to a given value K

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hashmap

Given an array A of size N, find all combinations of four elements in the array whose sum is equal to a given value K. For example, if the given array is {10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8} and K = 23, one of the quadruple is “3 5 7 8” (3 + 5 + 7 + 8 = 23).

The output should contain only unique quadruple For example, if the input array is {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} and K = 4, then the output should be only one quadruple {1, 1, 1, 1}

**My approach:** I tried to solve this problem by storing all the distinct pairs formed from the given array into a hash table (`std::unordered_multimap`), with their sum as key. Then for each pair sum, I looked for (K - sum) key in the hash table. The problem with this approach is I am getting too many duplicated like (i, j, l, m) and (i, l, j, m) are the same, plus there are duplicates due to the same items in the array. I am not sure what is the optimal way to address that.

The code for the above-mentioned approach is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    size_t tc = 0;
    std::cin >> tc; //number of test cases
    while(tc--) {
        size_t n = 0, k = 0;
        std::cin >> n >> k;
        std::vector<size_t> vec(n);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            std::cin >> vec[i];

        std::unordered_multimap<size_t, std::tuple<size_t, size_t>> m;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            const auto sum = vec[i] + vec[j];
            m.emplace(sum, std::make_tuple(i, j));
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            const auto sum = vec[i] + vec[j];
            auto r = m.equal_range(k - sum);
            for (auto it = r.first; it != r.second; ++it) {
                if ((i == std::get<0>(it->second))
                ||(i == std::get<1>(it->second))
                ||(j == std::get<0>(it->second))
                || (j == std::get<1>(it->second)))
                continue;
                std::cout << vec[i] << ' ' << vec[j] << ' ' 
                << vec[std::get<0>(it->second)] << ' '
                << vec[std::get<1>(it->second)] << '$';
            }

            r = m.equal_range(sum);
            for (auto it = r.first; it != r.second; ++it) {
                if ((i == std::get<0>(it->second))
                && (j == std::get<1>(it->second))) {
                    m.erase(it);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code will run as-is in the link mentioned below in the Note.

Note: This problem is taken from https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-all-four-sum-numbers/0

Comment: This is the "target sum" problem with restrictions of a subset size, and no duplicate solutions.  Please research the solutions posted on Stack Overflow and elsewhere  before posting here; the duplicate avoidance is also covered in this group.

Comment: See one general solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671356/all-possible-combination-of-n-numbers-to-sum-x)

Answer (score 0):

To handle duplicate values in array

Consider `[2, 2, 2, 3, 3]` with goal `10`.

The only solution is the `4-tuple` `<2,2,3,3>`. The main point is to avoid choosing two 2 among three 2.

Let's consider the `k-class`, the set of tuples in which every tuple contain only `k`.

e.g: in our array we have the `2-class` and `3-class`.
The `2-class` contains:

```
<2>
<2,2>
<2,2,2>
```

while the `3-class` contains:

```
<3>
<3,3>
```

An idea is to reduce the array of elem (elem being an integer value) to an array of `k-class`.
idem

```
[[<2>, <2,2>, <2,2,2>], [<3>, <3,3>]]
```

We can think of taking the cartesian product between the `2-class` set and the `3-class` set, and check which result lead to solution.

More concretely, let's take some tuple `T`, whose last (==rightmost) value is `k`. (in `<2,3,4>` rightmost value would be `4`).

We can pick any `l-class` from our array (* `l > k`) and join the tuples from that `l-class` to `T`.

e.g

- consider array `[2, 9, 9, 3, 3, 4, 6]` and tuple `<2, 3, 3>`
- The rightmost value is `3`.
- The candidate `k-class` are `4-class`, `6-class`, `9-class`

we can join:

```
<4>
<6>
<9>
<9,9>
```

so the next candidates will be:

```
<2, 3, 3, 4>
<2, 3, 3, 6>
<2, 3, 3, 9>
<2, 3, 3, 9, 9> //that one has too many elem, left for illustration
```

(* The purpose of `l > k` is to prevent the permutation. (if `<1,2>` is solution you don't want `<2,1>` since addition is commutative))

#### Algorithm

```
Foreach tuple, try to create new ones by rightjoining tuples from a "greater" k-class.
discard the resulting ones which have too many elements or whose sum is already too big...
At some point we won't have new candidates, so algorithm will stop
```

example of cuts:

1. given array `[2,3,7,8,10,11]`, and tuple `<2,3>` and `S == 13`

   - `<2,3,7>` is candidate (2+3+7 = 12 < 13)
   - `<2,3,10>` is **not** candidate (2+3+10 = 15 > 13)
   - `<2,3,11>` even more so. **not**
   - `<2,3,8>` is not candidate either since the next rightjoin (to reach a `4-tuple`) will overflow `S`
2. given array `[2,3,4,4,4]` given tuple `<2,3>` and candidate `<4,4,4>`

resulting tuple would be `<2,3,4,4,4>` which has too many elems, discard it!

Obviously the initialization is

- some empty tuple
- whose sum is 0
- and whose rightmost element is less than any `k` from the array (you can rightjoin it anybody)

I believe it should not be too hard to translate to `C++`

```js
class TupleClass {
  sum = 0
  rightIdx = -1
  values = [] // an array of integers (hopefully summing to solution)

  //idx is the position of the k-class found in array
  add (val, idx) {
    const t = new TupleClass()
    t.values = this.values.concat(val)
    t.sum = this.sum + val
    t.rightIdx = idx

    return t;
  }

  toString () {
    return `<${this.values.join(',')}>`
  }

  addTuple (tuple, idx) {
    const t = new TupleClass
    t.values = this.values.concat(tuple.values)
    t.sum = this.sum + tuple.sum
    t.rightIdx = idx

    return t;
  }
  get size () {
    return this.values.length
  }
}

function nodupes (v, S) {

  v = v.reduce((acc, klass) => {
    acc[klass] = (acc[klass] || {duplicity: 0, klass})
    acc[klass].duplicity++
    return acc
  }, {})
  v = Object.values(v).sort((a,b) => a.klass - b.klass).map(({ klass, duplicity }, i) => {
    return Array(duplicity).fill(0).reduce((acc, _) => {
      const t = acc[acc.length-1].add(klass, i)
      acc.push(t)
      return acc
    }, [new TupleClass()]).slice(1)
  })
  //v is sorted by k-class asc
  //each k-class is an array of tuples with increasing length
  //[[<2>, <2,2>, <2,2,2>], [<3>,<3,3>]]
  let tuples = [new TupleClass()]
  const N = v.length

  let nextTuples = []

  const solutions = []
  while (tuples.length) {
    tuples.forEach(tuple => {
      //foreach kclass after our rightmost value
      for (let j = tuple.rightIdx + 1; j <= N - 1; ++j) {

        //foreach tuple of that kclass
        for (let tclass of v[j]) {
          const nextTuple = tuple.addTuple(tclass, j)

          if (nextTuple.sum > S || nextTuple.size > 4) {
            break
          }

          //candidate to solution
          if (nextTuple.size == 4) {
            if (nextTuple.sum === S) {
              solutions.push(nextTuple)
            }
            //invalid sum so adding more elem won't help, do not push
          } else {
            nextTuples.push(nextTuple)
          }
          
        }
      }
    })
    tuples = nextTuples
    nextTuples = []
  }
  return solutions;
}
const v = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,0,0]
const S = 7
console.log('v:', v.join(','), 'and S:',S)
console.log(nodupes(v, 7).map(t=>t.toString()).join('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, I need to go through your code to understand it better. In the meanwhile can you please tell me what is the time complexity of this solution. I am looking for a solution which is `O(n^2)`, using hash table.

Comment: That'd be O(k^4) where k is the number of classes. (C_k^4).

Comment: An slight optimization would be to cache a few sums by considering that 4 can be decomposed as 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+3, 2+2
that is compute all the  ```1+1```-tuple (1-tuple from two different classes), then rightjoin them themselves (which makes the 1+1+1+1 sum). Use it as well for 1+1+2 (where we already computed the 2-tuple of every k-class). But I haven't timed it so beware

Comment: And likely to refer to your hash table, instead of storing the tuples in an array, better consider a multimap: the key is the sum, and for values the associated tuples.
since we are crossing the values associated of a key (left tuples) to those associated to S-key right tuples), we can just break the permutation by enforcing that ```leftTuple.rightMost < rightTuple.leftMost```